# Xcode Custom view constraints not updating when updating size programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom UIView that has 2 UILabel's which I have designed in the XIB. Have set the correct constraints to the sub items making them right aligned etc. In the XIB, my desgin was based on the assumption that screen width is 200 and constraints of the 2 labels are set to their superview accordingly.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
    //_intrinsicContentSize = self.bounds.size; // tried to return this as well
}
return self;
}
```

[image: XIB Design]

Now I programmatically alloc this view and and add it as subview to my view controller. If I change the frame of the view to say 300, the sub view frame gets changed to 300 but the 2 labels which have constraints follow a width of 200 only.

```
        vewOneTouch = [[OneTouchView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMinY(vewBottom.frame)-50, CGRectGetWidth(scwBaseView.frame), 50)];
[scwBaseView addSubview:vewOneTouch];
```

When the custom view frame is changed, why are the constraints not kicking in and changing the layout of all the items in the subview?

[image: View in Simulator after changing subview frames] The white area is the yellow view in the Xib, have changed the color programmatically.

Comment: where you are giving viewonetouch method

Comment: Are you sure the view frame is changed ? What constraints do you use for the labels ?

Comment: Have you set width constraints for the items or aligned them to the ends of the superview?

Comment: @B K Add the one line of code.... to update view [self.view layoutIFNeeded]

Comment: @AshokLondhe setNeedsLayout did not help. Even Tried layout

Comment: @A-Live for the Yellow View above, I am setting constrains of match parent. But it clearly does not match parents.

Comment: @BK I think you had not set the constraint properly... Have you added fixed width constraint to UILabels. If yes please remove it and try.

Comment: @AshokLondhe No the constraints are correct, match parent for the yellow view, and the labels have a width equals the yellow view with a multiplication factor of 0.2

Comment: @BK Are you on Skype . I am not getting your problem exactly.

Comment: @BK your problem is solved or not?

Comment: Hey @AshokLondhe its still not solved. I will try to share a sample project with my problem, will try to upload it else plz give me your skype id.

Comment: @BK my skype id... ashok.londhe1